# React Design - Parent / Child Interaction with Async State

Tags: async, component, react

I have a situation involving a parent component, children, and async fetch operations, and I am wondering how to best structure it.

The current code structure I have is as follows:

I have a parent component with a textbox. When the user types in the box, it triggers our debounced API call.

```
useEffect(() => {
  debouncedApiCall();
  return () => debouncedApicall.cancel();
}, [textboxState]);
```

In the `debouncedApiCall`, I can discern if the user is searching for a profile, or for a thread via regex (the textbox acts as an omnibox). Based on the type of thing they query, I do the appropriate api lookup, gather data, and update a state.

Then, I conditionally render a child component, either `Profile` if they queried a profile, or `Post` if they queried a post. I pass in the data from the API, and these are rendered.

I'm wondering, is it better design to have each child instead handle its own API lookup? So I conditionally render the appropriate child, but instead I now pass in the searched text, rather than the result of the API call. The reason I am considering this is it can give the children more ownership of when they are loading, which helps me render appropriate spinner icons more easily. As a new coder, I often have trouble avoiding antipatterns and deciding on good code design, so I would really appreciate any thoughts.

However, in my current code, I can nicely trigger just one debounced api call. If I switch to the new idea, I don't see how I would handle this as easily.